# two circles should follow the cursor – one small and one big (with delay)

Tags: javascript, html, css, cursor

I have seen this tendency on some websites now, where the default cursor is replaced with a new cursor – in many cases circles

These cursors are interactive – with interactive i mean when hovering an a-tag it changes size and color.

On this website: https://en.leviev-group.com/ you can see the effect on the cursor that I want.

I have tried to make a Pen, but it isn't working properly: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VQwdBv?q=cursor&limit=all&type=type-pens

```
<div id="cursor">
<div id="circle-big"></div>
<div id="circle"></div>
</div>
```

I would like the circle in the middle to be the cursor and the big circle around to follow the cursor with delay.
When hovering a-tags it should wrap around the a-tag, similar to the example on the website. If possible made with javascript and css

How is this possible?

Comment: I'm not sure why you don't implement the cursor with a `cursor` property rather than using a div. Anyway, but you're on the right track; changing the #circle to position:absolute and the generated coordinates to d.pageX and d.pageY will go a long way.

Comment: wouldn't you have to add an image to the cursor property to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost good, simply make both element behave the same and by adding the transition on the small one you will make it slower and create the follow effect.

```js
$('body').mouseover(function() {
  $(this).css({
    cursor: 'none'
  });
});

$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
  $('#circle-big').css({
    left: e.pageX,
    top: e.pageY
  });
  $('#circle').css({
    left: e.pageX,
    top: e.pageY
  });

});
```

```css
#circle-big {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-left: -30px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  z-index: -1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#circle {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  transition: all 1s linear;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin-top: -7.5px;
  margin-left: -7.5px;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

a {
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 100px auto;
  display: block;
}

a:hover {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cursor">
  <div id="circle-big"></div>
  <div id="circle"></div>
</div>

<a>link</a>
```

Or change the transition if you want the bigger one to follow the small one:

```js
$('body').mouseover(function() {
  $(this).css({
    cursor: 'none'
  });
});

$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
  $('#circle-big').css({
    left: e.pageX,
    top: e.pageY
  });
  $('#circle').css({
    left: e.pageX,
    top: e.pageY
  });

});
```

```css
#circle-big {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-left: -30px;
  transition: all 1s linear;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  z-index: -1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#circle {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin-top: -7.5px;
  margin-left: -7.5px;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

a {
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 100px auto;
  display: block;
}

a:hover {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cursor">
  <div id="circle-big"></div>
  <div id="circle"></div>
</div>

<a>link</a>
```

**UPDATE**

You may consider event on links tag if you want to change the cursor when hovering links.

Here is a simple example:

```js
$('body').mouseover(function() {
  $(this).css({
    cursor: 'none'
  });
});

$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
  $('#circle-big').css({
    left: e.pageX,
    top: e.pageY
  });
  $('#circle').css({
    left: e.pageX,
    top: e.pageY
  });
});
$('a').mouseover(function() {
  $('#cursor').addClass('on-link');
})
$('a').mouseout(function() {
  $('#cursor').removeClass('on-link');
})
```

```css
#circle-big {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-left: -30px;
  transition: all 1s linear;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  z-index: -1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#circle {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin-top: -7.5px;
  margin-left: -7.5px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

#cursor.on-link #circle-big {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

a {
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 100px auto;
  display: block;
}

a:hover {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cursor">
  <div id="circle-big"></div>
  <div id="circle"></div>
</div>

<a>link</a>
```

Comment: Ahhh okay – the last example seems to be on the right path, but how can this be made, so the big circle expands when hovering the link?

Comment: @DWTBC for the second feature you can add event on mousehover/mouseout of links and you change the CSS of the circle to make it bigger or any other style .. am gonna make a code ;)

Comment: @DWTBC added a simple example that you can improve ;)