# Why do two circles as a cursor cause a vertical or horizontal scrollbar?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm developing a website, and I wanted to have two circles as a cursor. I've already found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48509800/two-circles-should-follow-the-cursor-one-small-and-one-big-with-delay) on how to do that, but the problem is that when I move the mouse all the way to the right or down, these two circles cause a vertical or horizontal scrollbar.

This code is a copy-paste from the link above, so you can try to move the mouse to the bottom of the screen and see what I'm talking about.

I want to prevent both scrollbars so when you move the mouse all the way to the right or down, nothing happens.

See the snippet below.

```js
$('body').mouseover(function() {
  $(this).css({
    cursor: 'none'
  });
});

$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
  $('#circle-big').css({
    left: e.pageX,
    top: e.pageY
  });
  $('#circle').css({
    left: e.pageX,
    top: e.pageY
  });

});
```

```css
#circle-big {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-left: -30px;
  transition: all 1s linear;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  z-index: -1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#circle {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin-top: -7.5px;
  margin-left: -7.5px;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

a {
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 100px auto;
  display: block;
}

a:hover {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cursor">
  <div id="circle-big"></div>
  <div id="circle"></div>
</div>

<a>link</a>
```

Comment: one line of CSS `body {cursor: none;}` could spare several in jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the overflow on the body to hidden `body{overflow:hidden;}`

```js
$('body').mouseover(function() {
  $(this).css({
    cursor: 'none'
  });
});

$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
let xy = {
    left: e.pageX,
    top: e.pageY
  };
  $('#circle-big').add('#circle').css(xy);
});
```

```css
#circle-big {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-left: -30px;
  transition: all 1s linear;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  z-index: -1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#circle {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin-top: -7.5px;
  margin-left: -7.5px;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

a {
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 100px auto;
  display: block;
}

a:hover {
  font-size: 30px;
}
body{overflow:hidden;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cursor">
  <div id="circle-big"></div>
  <div id="circle"></div>
</div>
<a>link</a>
```